# Monitor pulsing and lines/streaks

Tags: display

I have a problem with a Samsung (U32E850R) 4k 31.5" monitor purchased in 2016: It shows a pattern of pixilated "streaks" vertical and horizontal and undulating pulsing on the left side. This is irrespective of the cables used -- tried both mini dp to displayport and mini dp to mini dp. Even with no cables attached, streaking is visible (monitor is slightly backlit when trying to find input source). It seems similar to this posting but I suspect monitor hardware and not cables:
[Possible causes of "streaks" on LCD monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/82536/possible-causes-of-streaks-on-lcd-monitor)

The video source (macbook pro) doesn't appear to be the issue because swapping with a different monitor makes this go away.

So the question: anything I can do to remedy this?

Link to an image of the monitor: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1L3S.jpg

Comment: You wrote "Even with no cables attached, streaking is visible" I would suggest getting it serviced as it definitely appears to have a hardware error

Comment: I agree that it is a hardware issue and called a repair shop but was told not to bother-- low replacement costs don't make repairs a good option (he quoted ~$150 -$250). I purchased a monitor of the same size but lower resolution for roughly the cost of repairs and will donate the broken monitor to a company that recycles and donates proceeds to charity.